# Can we express the Lebesgue outer measure with closed intervals?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Can we say that:

$$\mu^{*}(E) = \inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu^{*}([a_i,b_i]): E\subseteq \bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}[a_i,b_i] a_i,b_i\in \mathbb{R}\right\}?$$

Comment: Yes, you can. Every open interval is contained in the corresponding closed interval and every closed interval $[a,b]$ is contained in $(a-\frac {\epsilon} {2^{i}}, b+\frac {\epsilon} {2^{i}})$.

Comment: Yes, eventually it doesn't matter whether you use open, closed, left/right open intervals (but of course the equivalence has to be proven).